# Why does jinja isn't working for simple template

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to create html document from html-template and python

Html template

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)">
<title>Договор подряда № 8/003-07 на выполнение проектных работ</title>
<style>
</style>

</head>
<body bgcolor=white lang=RU>
<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-right:-1.15pt;text-align:center'><b><span
style='font-size:12.0pt'>Договор подряда № {{document_number}}</span></b></p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to fill **document_number ** but instead of value i have empty line ""
How can I fix it?

**My code**

```
import jinja2  # create html files

templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(
    searchpath="./"
)
data_to_render = {
    "document_number": "123",
    "building_object_address": "Moscow"
}
#templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(
  loader=templateLoader,
  comment_start_string='{=',
  comment_end_string='=}',
)
template = templateEnv.get_template("income_contract_short.html")
sourceHtml = template.render(json_data=data_to_render)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing your data to template.render as `json_data`, so the only variable available to the template is `json_data`, which you have to access like a dictionary.

**Option 1:**
In the template, replace `{{document_number}}` with `{{json_data['document_number']}}`

**Option 2:**
Pass your data elements as separate keyword arguments to template.render, changing:
`sourceHtml = template.render(json_data=data_to_render)` 
to 
`sourceHtml = template.render(document_number=data_to_render["document_number"], address=data_to_render["building_object_address"])`

You could then access the building_object_address data as simply {{address}}.